# Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2, upgrade

I tried to install extension from the magento market place but I got incompatibility error..

Problem 1

- magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 3
- laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 1.0.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.4].
- magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.

how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 10):

You can downgrade your Composer to version 1.x

```sh
composer self-update --1
```

And if you need to switch back to Composer version 2.x, you can just type

```sh
composer self-update --2
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from it. Also, please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.x is not yet compatible with composer 2.x

You can either:

- downgrade your system version of Composer to 1.x
- download composer 1.x phar file and run local version (preferable)

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Current version is 1.10.19

then run the command using the local composer version:

```
php ./composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not support Composer 2.x. please ref the link:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html may help you